# Если функция возвращает либо объет, либо false, как правильно присвоить её результат переменной

Tags: typescript

У меня есть интерфейс, есть функция, которая делает какуе-то проверку и по результатом возвращает, либо объет соответсвующий интерфейсу, либо false. Вот примерный код моей проблемы.

```
interface someInterface {
  test1: 1;
  test2: 2
}

function someFun(): someInterface | boolean {
  if (true) {
    return {
      test1: 1,
      test2: 2
    };
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

let someVar: someInterface | boolean = someFun();

let anotherVar = someVar ? someVar.test1 : someVar;
```

В последней строке `let anotherVar = someVar.test1;` typeScript подчёркивает ошибку и пишет:

> Свойство "test1" не существует в типе "boolean | someInterface".
> Свойство "test1" не существует в типе "false".

Как правильно на TS надо написать этот кусок кода, чтобы ошибка ушла?

Я подозреваю, что, наверное, как-то через дженейрики надо это делать, но я пока плохо понимаю, как их писать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае используется не совсем корректный возвращаемый тип для функции.

На самом деле функция возвращает не `someInterface | boolean`, а `someInterface | false`

Если использовать правильный тип, все работает корректно

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=37&pln=6&pc=42#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgM4HsC2ECS5rxLIDeAUMspKmAIwBcyNA3OZRNQEwMekC+ppGAFcQCMMHQg0WCADERACgCUDDNjyRYiFAB9k8ADaoUZCsBjIFYKEIhKSrClAhghUKaYpeqtBjQA0jt7sYFzIPF7IvCwUvMgQRiZBzq7u+nCJMVF8AgYu0tgAanBQqjIaBNrIegBG6Oh5cFIAvAVyikospHlgyE3oYAAW0MVQyK1qEKPIAPxtowB0PjTIZUUlTEA)

первый вариант не работает, ввиду того, что `boolean` имеет два возможных значения и после проверки объект может быть либо интерфейсом, либо `true`, и у такого объединения нет поля `test1`.

Альтернативным способом решения может быть проверка именно типа переменной, с помощью `typeof`

```
let anotherVar = typeof someVar !== 'boolean' ? someVar.test1 : someVar;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=73&pln=19&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgM4HsC2ECS5rxLIDeAUMspKmAIwBcyNA3OZRNQEwMekC+ppGAFcQCMMHQg0WCADERACgCUDDNjyRYiFAB9kAI3ToANhDhSyFYDGQKwUIRCUlWFKBDBCoF1xTbV6RgAaXwoqMC5kHj9kXhYKXmQIY1QUSz93T29keBSIeNi+AVMwaWwANTgoVRkNAm1kPUMTMykAXjK5RSUWUhLkc3QwAAtoSqhkDrAATwAHCHQbNQhx5ABCNo6AcmbTcy3kAH5O8YA6cJpkGoqqpiA)